# Linq: Split contents of a string column and add it to the array returned by Select(o=>o.ColumnName)

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

A database column contains following values
`SampleColumnValues

T1

T2

T3,T4

T5,T6

T7

T8`

When, I try to read these values, it is perfectly possible using the IQueryable.Select() method to get this specific column from DB and convert it to an array using ToArray().
But, I also need the comma delimited values in the originally returned array as individual array elements.

For now, I have a separate method to do the additional splitting.
Can I achieve the same with stock methods available?

The resultant array I need should be like `{T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string[] input = new string[] { "T1", "T2", "T3,T4", "T5,T6", "T7", "T8" };

string[] output = input.SelectMany(item => item.Split(',')).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the Aggregate function...
`...Select(o => o.ColumnName).Aggregate((w, n) => w + "," + n).Split(',');`

Comment: No need to call ToArray() in order to do aggregate - this is a waste. As a whole it's not very optimal - you don't need to concatenate at all (see my answer)

Comment: @fiver: You are right, indeed I removed it from the implemented solution forgot to get rid of it here.